# Can black image on photo strip be saved?

Tags: film, photo-booth

I'm someone who knows nothing about photography at all. That said, I was wondering if it'd be possible to save an image taken at a booth you can go in at fairs or whatever and it'll take your picture and print out a photo strip?

Well me and the boyfriend did just that. It was a really old school picture box. It printed the pictures in black and white, and the last picture on the strip is only partially developed. I thought it was maybe like an old Polaroid and it'd just develop as the night went on, but it didn't. It's just dark and you can't see it! I was wondering if there's any quick fix so I can save the picture. I apologize if I used any wrong terms! Thanks! (:

Comment: what is "this image"? Are you able to link in a copy of the photo?

Comment: You may want to edit this question to change "film strip" to "photo strip"; "picture box" to "photobooth"; and "Kodak" to "Polaroid". :)

Comment: I'd guess "probably not" BUT try shining a very bright light through it and see if you have any image detail visible. If so you can adjust brightness level and take a photo (macro mode if possible so image fills frame) with lighting level that works best. A scanner with adjustable brightness / contrast settings may do the same but usually with less resolution than a camera.

Comment: If you are asking about the old photo booths that take four shots which are delivered as a vertical print of the four images, then what you have is not a film strip (negative), but a photographic print (positive). The old booths used a chemical process to develop the prints and once the strip pops out of the machine, it does so fully developed and fixed and won't develop further.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's very unlikely that the photos can be saved without any really advanced techniques.  (There are some technologies that can rescue historical photos and make the image visible, although the quality of the resulting image may not be very good.  The technologies are, alas, often expensive and limited to items of great historical value.)

If the images are very dark but with some obvious image detail present, it's possible that using a photographic chemical like Farmer's reducer might partially save them, but if the images are completely black, there will be no detail to salvage, I suspect.